# Log to console key press, including repeat presses

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get arrow key presses in javascript. Currently, I can log to console the key that is last pressed. However, if I wanted to output the same key multiple times, I am not able to until another key is pressed. My code for getting keypress instances is this currently:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    var key = event.key;
    if (key = "ArrowUp"){
        console.log("up");
        return false;
    } else if (key = "ArrowDown"){
        console.log("down");
        return false;
    }
});
```

I have also tried using a switch statements for the keypresses, but the problem still remained. Using jquery isn't a problem for me here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `==` or `===` in the `if` condition for this to work correctly,

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    var key = event.key;
    if (key === "ArrowUp"){
        console.log("up");
        return false;
    } else if (key === "ArrowDown"){
        console.log("down");
        return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<p> press up/down key for logs to appear </p>
```

Comment: So my actual problem wasn't actually the equals signs (although it was a problem), but for some reason, I didn't realize that firefox doesn't repeatedly output to the console when its the same phrase. So it was working the entire time, but I mistakenly ignored the counter that showed it repeating.

Answer (score 1):

Please use **==** or **===** equality operators while checking for key. By use a single **= sign you are assigning key variable to "ArrowUp" and "ArrowDown" values** instead of checking against them.